# ASM constraints side effects

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm having a hard time understanding some effects of some specific
constraints in GCC for inline-assembly.

I the below example, if I run with "=X" on the output and "X" on all the inputs, the 2 prints output

> 0x562f39629260, 100
>
> 0x14, 100

Which indicates that the pointer to the buffer that I allocated has changed. Leading to a Segfault is a try to read the content of the buffer
after my assembly code.

On the contrary, If i put "+X" on the output or "m" in the inputs then
the addresses stay the same, the prints output:

> 0x55571bb83260, 100
>
> 0x55571bb83260, 100

And I can safely read my buffer without segfaulting.

I don't understand how or why this pointer should/could be modified?
Is there a way to safely choose constraints? The gcc online documentation
does not give much insight on this.

Thanks a lot,

```
int main() {
    long size = 100;
    char * buffer = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));

    printf("%p, %d\n",buffer, size);

    __asm__(
    "mov %[out], %%rcx \n"
    "mov %[size], %%rbx \n"
    "loop: \n"
    "movb $1, (%%rcx) \n"
    "add $1, %%rcx \n"
    "sub $1, %%rbx \n"
    "jnz loop \n"
    : "=X"(buffer) //outputs
    : [out]"X"(buffer), [size]"X"(size) //inputs
    : "rbx", "rcx" //clobbers
    );

    printf("%p, %d\n",buffer, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `buffer` an output? Also why on earth are you using `X` constraint? Of course `=X` breaks `buffer` ... you basically told the compiler that it should fetch a new value for `buffer` from wherever it wants and you have not even referenced that argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=` in `=X` means this is an OUTPUT ONLY constraint (as opposed to an update constraint with `+`).  This means that the assembly code is expected to to write something to the operand (to `%0`) and that will ben the value that is output.  But since your assembler code never writes to `%0`, you get whatever garbage happens to be in that location (probably a register that the register allocator picked).

Try adding a `mov %%rcx,%0` line to the asm code to see what actually happens.

Most likely what you really want is something more like:

```
__asm__ volatile (
"mov %[size], %%rbx \n"
"loop: \n"
"movb $1, (%[out]) \n"
"add $1, %[out] \n"
"sub $1, %%rbx \n"
"jnz loop \n"
: [out]"+r"(buffer) //outputs
: [size]"X"(size) //inputs
: "rbx", "memory" //clobbers
);
```

Note that this leaves `buffer` pointing after the inserted values (at the end of the buffer) -- not clear if that is what you want.  You can do the same with size, making it even simpler:

```
__asm__ volatile (
"loop: \n"
"movb $1, (%[out]) \n"
"add $1, %[out] \n"
"sub $1, %[size] \n"
"jnz loop \n"
: [out]"+r"(buffer), [size]"+X"(size) //outputs
: //inputs
: "memory" //clobbers
);
```

Though it would be even simpler (and better for the optimizer) to not use asm at all:

```
do { *buffer++ = '\1'; } while (--size);
```

---

So to summarize all the comments below, what you might want is something like:

```
long size = 100;
char buffer[100];
char *temp;
__asm__(
"loop: \n"
"movb $1, (%[out]) \n"
"add $1, %[out] \n"
"sub $1, %[size] \n"
"jnz loop \n"
: [out]"=r"(temp), [size]"+X"(size), "=m"(buffer) //outputs
: "0"(buffer) // inputs
)  // no clobbers
```

- using an `"=m"` constraint on the entire buffer instead of a memory clobbers and volatile means that it can be dead-code eliminated if none of the results are used
- using a temp for the pointer being advanced over the buffer means the original buffer (start) value can be preserved.
- if you must use malloc for the buffer `"=m"(*(char (*)[100])buffer)` can be used to get the constraint on the entire buffer.

Hoever, I stand by my earlier comment that writing it without asm is better; it's simpler and easier to understand and the compiler's optimizer will probably vectorize it for you.

Comment: It would be a simplification to pass size through just a register and make it a `+r` constraint then you can remove the first `mov` since the assembler will put the value in it for you. There is a bug in this albeit subtle. Passing an address to data via a register doesn't guarantee the object has been fully realize into memory. `"+r"(buffer)` says that the pointer to buffer will be placed in a compiler chosen register and that the pointer will be used as an input operand and that the pointer in the register will be modified, not the data it points to.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: you are correct in that it needs a `"memory"` clobbers to note that it  reads and writes memory, but trying to use `"+m"(*buffer)` won't work as the asm code tries to indirect through a register.

Comment: +@MichaelPetch: `"+m"(*buffer)` only tells the compiler the *first* byte is an input/output.  That might be sufficient here for newly-allocated memory, but the currently-recommended syntax is casting to a pointer-to-array and dereferencing.  I recently updated my answer on [Looping over arrays with inline assembly](//stackoverflow.com/q/34244185) with unknown / known size versions of that syntax: For this case, you can use `[dummy] "+m" (*(char(*)[100]) buffer)`  *as well* as the `[out] "+r"(buffer)` that you actually use.  If this is safe without early-clobbers, dummy can use the same pointer

Comment: @PeterCordes :I had typed it upon my phone on the way out and I wasn't really thinking at the time. I wanted to actually point out originally was that `malloc` is pointless here as it isn't freed.and will go out of scope anyway I'd put a local array of 100 characters on the stack (`char buffer[100]`) and then would have considered `: [out]"+m"(buffer)` . In that case it would be the whole array. Changing how the array is created was my original intent and then I sloughed off a comment I regret making..

Comment: @MichaelPetch: oh neat, I hadn't thought about the "base case" of that dereference pointer-to-array, but now it makes sense that you get the whole array contents, not decay-to-pointer for `"+m"(buffer)`.

Comment: @Chris: see my first comment for a way that makes this safe *without* a `"memory"` clobber and without `volatile`.  (With yours, the array contents side-effect isn't visible to the compiler via an output constraint, so it could optimize away the asm statement if you don't use `size` or the modified copy of the pointer afterward. Only an `asm` with no outputs is implicitly volatile).  And BTW, I should have used `"=m" (*(char(*)[100]) buffer)` because it *is* output-only.  We don't want to tell the compiler we read uninitialized data with `"+m"` when we actually don't.

Comment: Ah I misread the code originally, I thought the `movb` was also an `addb` so I assumed the array was input/output. Clearly it is just output.So any where I said `+m` should have simply been `=m`

Comment: Thanks for your answers and all the precisions, about putting in C, of course it's better, my question originates from a more complex SIMD code that i simplified to show my problem. Now i get it more clearly. Just one last thing, as the bufffer address is incremented, how can i read the buffer after the code ? say i want to print it , did i loose the address of the first byte of buffer ?

Comment: @JeanMi: Use a `int *asm_input = buffer;` tmp var, or use separate input and output variables (with a `"0" (buffer)` matching constraint for the input), with a dummy output.  Or just put your asm block inside a `static inline` wrapper function, so you take a copy of the variable that way without affecting the caller's copy of the variables.  But really, for x86 you should normally use intrinsics.  Compilers are definitely not always perfect, but it's more portable and usually good enough to use intrinsics.  (And you have to be an expert to beat compilers, e.g. http://agner.org/optimize/)